# DIsplay date before title using WP_LIST_PAGES

Tags: wordpress

The default formatting puts the date after the title, I want the date to be displayed first and then the title, I also want to be able to separate them a little bit and make them look nice and lined up with a left justification.

The code is set to display a list of all the subpages of page.

```
<?php  
   wp_list_pages( array(
      'title_li' => '', 
      'child_of' => 701, 
      'show_date' => '1', 
   ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find option to modify it from PHP. So, here is small CSS tweak so that you can get date in the front. Check this:

```
<style>
  #page-list li{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
  }
  #page-list li a{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
</style>
<ul id="page-list">
<?php
   wp_list_pages( array(
      'title_li' => '',
      'child_of' => 701,
      'show_date' => '1',
   ) ); ?>
</ul><!-- #page-list -->
```

Comment: Thank you Nilambar, this worked almost perfectly, I had to tweak it a little bit, but this is what I needed.